# SharePoint Online-Communication Site-Not able to achieve this color scheme

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site

I am trying to achieve the color scheme described below. The modern "Change the Look" allows one to customize colors but doesn't allow us to add a background Image which the classic "Change the look" supports. The Classic "Change the Look" doesn't have a color palette with a white Header and a dark body. I tried following this blog https://blog.pixelmill.com/3348/changing-colors-modern-site/  about adding a custom Theme via Powershell, but it doesn't allow you to add an Image.

As mentioned in the diagram, I would also like to add a layer of color over the Top Nav.

How can I achieve the color scheme mentioned below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only change the color of the modern site pages, we can add a custom theme via PowerShell to achieve it.

If you want to add a background Image, we have to use SPFx extension to injects CSS to achieve it in modern page.

Refer to: [react-application-injectcss](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

Or use [react script editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) with custom CSS style to achieve it.